# В чем ошибка, просто хочу прогу свою написать первую

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("Введите название планеты: "))
if a == Земля :
    print("Масса (по отношению к Земле) - 1")
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DeeSto\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    a = int(input("Введите название планеты: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Земля'
```

Answer (score 2):

у вас мешанина

1. требуете ввести название планеты, а переводите ее в число
2. масса по отношению к массе Земли подразумевает `float`, а вы используете `int`
3. вы сравниваете с непонятной сущностью `Земля` - это название переменной или значение?

У вас так что ли должно было быть?

```
planet = input("Введите название планеты: ")
if planet == 'Земля':
    print("Масса (по отношению к Земле) - 1")
```

да и дальше непонятно, что вы хотите? получить отношение к массе? или что?

в общем какая логика вашей программы должна быть?

Comment: просто напросто вписать что он будет выводить типо print(1)

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем написать первую программу по Python надо прочитать первую книжку по Python. Или хотя-бы первые 10 страниц любой такой книжки. В которой объясняется, что такое переменная, какого типа переменные бывают, как зачем и когда переменные надо переводить из одного типа в другой.

Потом надо  сесть и самостоятельно подумать, задать себе несколько вопросов по своей программе.

Вопрос первый "А зачем я в строке `a = int(input("Введите название планеты: "))`название планеты преобразую в int тип?? Ведь int - это же означает "целое число". Как название планеты может быть целым числом"?

Потом задать себе второй вопрос "А что за бред я написал вот в этой строке `a == Земля` Если тут Земля - это название планеты, то оно -  как и любой строковый литерал -  должен быть заключен в скобки. А без скобок - это название переменной (правда в них кириллические буквы использовать запрещено, и это было написано на первой странице моей книги). А кроме того я ведь только что (чуть выше) объявил переменную `a` как целое число. Как же я мог целую переменную пытаться сравнивать со строкой символов".

И вот выполнив эти три действия  вы наконец сможете исполнить сокровенное желание, написать свою первую программу. Но если вы пропустите при этом действие номер один -  чтение книг -  то так и останетесь навсегда на уровне вопросов школьника пятого класса.

Comment: хех, спасибо, я просто не уследил и торопился вот и написал пурги)